# Prime rib weight on a restaurant menu - raw or cooked?

Tags: meat

When a restaurant menu lists a weight for a steak, I know it's raw weight. But when it lists the weight for prime rib, is it raw weight or cooked weight?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is consistent rule - I have seen restaurants sell meat in 100g portions, where they literally weigh it as they carve it off a large roast joint, and also restaurants where the raw weight is listed, then they roast a piece of meat of that weight (often for two or more to share).

The best policy is to ask each time!